# JQplot : blank chart when print IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, printing, jqplot

Hi
I have some problems using Jqplot with IE. 
All graphs I try to print are blank.
When i click on "preview before printing", the graph is displayed correctly. But when I really print the graph, there is no graph printed. Sometimes I can see some numbers on left or right borders of the graph, like if there was a white div above the graph, but no graph.

I have the same problem with any version of IE (6,7 or 8).
I have no problem with Firefox.

I have the problem even with examples files. You can download it at : 
http://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/downloads/jquery.jqplot.0.9.7r635.zip

Then go to the "examples" dir, then choose a .html file, like "test2.html".

One strange thing is that when i try to print graphs from the jqplot site,  i do not have this problem...

Does someone already has this problem ? Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution.

https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/268/blank-chart-when-print-ie

Comment out these lines at excanvas.js.

//var overlayEl = el.cloneNode(false);
// Use a non transparent background.
//overlayEl.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
//overlayEl.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
//canvasElement.appendChild(overlayEl);